# update CloudFront with new file on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How can I forced AWS CloudFront to pull new file from S3 as soon as the new file is uploaded to S3. I do not want to wait more then few seconds for the file to be available on AWS CloudFront service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Cache-Control" header on the object to "max-age: fewseconds"

And understand CloudFront Expiration rules:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html